# Where and when is Trigun Stampede set?

Tags: anime-history, trigun

I was watching episode five of Trigun Stampede and then this map came up:

[image]

This resembles breakup [Pangaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangaea). So I ask:

Where and when is Trigun Stampede set?

Comment: According to [wiki](https://trigun.fandom.com/wiki/Trigun_Stampede), it's in the same place and time where original *Trigun* was set: the planet No Man's Land (or Gunsmoke), in the distant future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime in the far future on the planet *No Man's Land* or *Gunsmoke*. The planet is located in the binary star system [Delta Trianguli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Trianguli). The story takes place around 150 years after humans arrived there.

> Project SEEDS is a deep space colonization mission in the anime and manga Trigun. The project's principal objective in the Trigun anime is the preservation of the human race after the original Earth's resources had been consumed while in the manga it is hinted that plant usage became widespread so that such catastrophe never took place. The project consists of a fleet of ships intent on the delivery of cold sleeping human populations to planets befitting the existence of life.

[Project SEEDS](https://trigun.fandom.com/wiki/Project_SEEDS)

> Not much is known about No Man's Land before the Project SEEDS starships crash-landed on its surface. However, several species of alien animals including sandworms and a group of sentient hive-minded insects lived on the desolate planet before "The Big Fall."

> For the next 150 years humanity would struggle to survive in the planet's desolate environment, utilizing plants found in the ruins of the crashed ships for food and water while building cities and towns around them. Over time what would become known as the Seven Cities would be built, making them the cultural and political hubs of the planet.

[Gunsmoke](https://trigun.fandom.com/wiki/Gunsmoke)